# Unable to Execute Test Case through TestNG

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

    public class TestNG {
        public WebDriver driver;

  @Test
      public void main() throws Exception {
      driver.findElement(By.id("account")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("********");
      driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("*****");
      driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
      System.out.println("Login Successfully :-)");
      driver.findElement(By.id("account_logout")).click();
      Thread.sleep(15000);
  }
  @BeforeMethod
      public void beforeMethod() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
  }

  @AfterMethod
      public void afterMethod() {
      driver.quit();
  }
}
```

*The @BeforeMethod ran successfully and launched the specified Website, but after the website has opened, it should move towards the main functionality i.e. @BeforeMethod, but unable to move further.
Please advise me, is there something wrong with the code.*

**Below Error we are getting:-**

[TestNG] Running:

```
C:\Users\gmohammad\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1784470156\testng-customsuite.xml

Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 6093
Only local connections are allowed.
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ghulam.TestNG.afterMethod(TestNG.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:703)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

FAILED: f
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ghulam.TestNG.f(TestNG.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@1a18493: 24 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@c0f91d: 148 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@de4588: 39 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@354949: 15 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@19b622d: 123 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 21 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code..

I guess this is happening due to declaring the driver again in your `@BeforeMethod` method making the driver object local to that method itself.

**Note** :- Tried executing your code, it is failing again at `"driver.findElement(By.id("account_logout")).click();"`.. please correct this and run again, it will work.

```
package testcases;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNG {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void main() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.id("account")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("********");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("*****");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        System.out.println("Login Successfully :-)");
        driver.findElement(By.id("account_logout")).click();
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://store.demoqa.com/");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, can you please let me know what changes you have made in my code apart from Chrome Driver Location! @M06494h

Comment: In your beforeMethod method I just changed as below, rest remains same. 
From
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
To
driver = new ChromeDriver();